# How to show a colored STL file in React app

Tags: reactjs, three.js, stl-format

I’m using React and want to show STL files in my app, more specifically, colored STL files. I have a binary STL colored file. 
Take for example a colored STL file from the three.js official website: https://threejs.org/examples/models/stl/binary/colored.stl.
You can see the colored file properly in http://www.viewstl.com/.
I saw that there are some packages like stl-viewer that shows very nicely STL files, but the color for the file needs to be added within the app.

I tried using stl-viewer using `modelColor` with `unset`.

```
<STLViewer
   url='https://threejs.org/examples/models/stl/binary/colored.stl'
   width={800}
   modelColor='unset'
   backgroundColor='#EAEAEA'
   rotate={false}
/>
```

I expect the viewer to show me the file with its colors, but the model got a basic color and didn't use its binary set of colors.

Maybe someone here encountered the same issue?
Does anyone here know a way that I can show my binary STL colored file in my React app??
Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up contributing to stl-viewer package and managed to support colored STL files.

So if this issue is relevant for someone here, i encourage you to check react-stl-viewer: https://github.com/chiedolabs/react-stl-viewer.

I'll update here when my contribution has been merged.

**Update: merged :)**